# ActionScript3 Exporting Issues

Tags: actionscript-3, export, keystroke

I have just started using actionscript three and I wrote code to make a movieclip moveable through keystrokes and a HitTest to make another movie clip run. When I preview it it all works fine. But when I publish it to html the key strokes stop working. The other animations are working fine, just the actions seem to be not exporting at all. What do I dooo?

Here is the code:

```
boat1_mc.x = 10
boat1_mc.x = 10
stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);

function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent) :void

{
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.RIGHT: boat1_mc.x += 5
        break;
        case Keyboard.LEFT: boat1_mc.x -= 5
        break;

        default :
        break;
    }
    if(boat1_mc.hitTestObject(tree_mc))
{
    tree_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
    boat1_mc.x = 10
    boat1_mc.x = 10

}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This may be too simple, but did you click in the swf to give it focus? When you first load the page keypresses go to the page itself; you need to click in the swf for keypresses to go there.

Comment: Yeah - I agree - focus need to be obtained.